# ComplexInfinity/Indeterminate error when evaluating derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages, operators

**Motivation:** I want to find the coefficients for the polynomial that is obtained when one adds together the first $n$ natural numbers to the power of $a$; that is, when you consider $1^{a} + 2^{a} + \cdots + n^{a}$.  The way I wanted to do this was: find the polynomial, then take the $j$-th derivative, evaluate at 0, and divide by $j!$.  My code to *just* obtain the polynomials and to take the derivatives are:

```
f[n_, a_] = Sum[i^(a), {i, 1, n}]
g[d_, a_, n_] = Derivative[d, 0][f][n, a]
```

So, for example, $g[1,2,n]$ is the first derivative (with respect to $n$) of the polynomial corresponding to $1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + n^2$.

**The Problem:** If I try $g[1,2,r]$ or $g[2,2,r]$, everything is fine.  If I attempt to try $g[3,2,r]$ (the third derivative, which should just be 2) I get the error:

```
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered. >>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong; this is true for $g[d,a,n]$ in general, if $d = a+1$.  I'm using Mathematica 8.

Comment: (1) It's not clear what "polynomial" this question refers to, because $1^a+\cdots+n^a$ is neither a polynomial in $n$ nor in $a$. It sounds rather like you are trying to develop a [MacLaurin series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html) in terms of $a$. (2) Have you looked at `Series`? Try, for example, `Table[Series[Sum[i^(a), {i, 1, n}], {a, 0, 4}] // FullSimplify, {n, 1,
    3}] // TableForm`

Comment: @whuber It seems he meant the result of $1^a +...+n^a$. It is a polynomial in `n`  for any natural number `a`.

Comment: Yes, @Artes, that makes sense: but taking the derivative with respect to $a$ requires $a$ to be a real number, not a natural number. I think this is goes to the heart of the difficulties, as analyzed in the answer by halirutan.

Comment: @whuber  In e.g. modern theoretical physics many problems require e.g. regularization techniques as a usual practice. I find this is a really nice question showing a common problem. I am a bit confused why it deserved (according to the community) only a few upvotes (far too few).

Answer (score 5):

Lets start step by step. First let us see that your sum is transformed into an build in function

```
Sum[i^a, {i, 1, r}]
(*  
  Out[36]= HarmonicNumber[r, -a]
*)
```

Now we can go two different ways: One way is to derivate this expression wrt `r` and keep the unknown `a`. Second is, we substitute `a->2` and derive afterwards. If we replace `a` by the number 2 we get the expected result

```
D[HarmonicNumber[r, -2], {r, 3}]
(*    
  Out[35]= 2
*)
```

If we don't replace it, we get another expression

```
D[HarmonicNumber[r, -a], {r, 3}]
(*
  Out[42]= -(1 - a) (2 - a) a (-HarmonicNumber[r, 3 - a] + Zeta[3 - a])
*)
```

If we replace `a->2` in this expression, we get in the last part `Zeta[1]` which is [infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta#Specific_values). I first thought this is maybe a bug in `D` which uses wrong assumptions. Indeet, if we don't stupidly substitute `a` by 2 but we calculate the `Limit` we get

```
Limit[-(1 - a) (2 - a) a (-HarmonicNumber[r, 3 - a] + Zeta[3 - a]), a -> 2]
(*
  Out[57]= 2
*)
```

Considering this, you could have ensured that first the numbers are inserted into your sum and then the derivation is done. As example you could have used this here

```
g[d_, a_] := Block[{n}, D[Sum[i^a, {i, 1, n}], {n, d}]]
```

which is neither perfect nor foolproof but it works for your example when used with numbers. Note that it still gives the same expression for an unknown `a`

```
g[3, a]
(*
  Out[55]= -(1 - a) (2 - a) a (-HarmonicNumber[n, 3 - a] + Zeta[3 - a])
*)
```

Comment: Whew, thank you for your analysis on that.  Yeah, I was wondering why there was an error; that explains it!

Answer (score 3):

Let's build the polynomial:

```
f[n_, a_] := Sum[i^(a), {i, 1, n}]
```

Now, build a function to take the `j-th` derivative of `f`:

```
g[j_, a_, n_] := D[f[n, a], {n, j}]
```

So with a=2:

```
f[n, 2] = 1/6 n (1 + n) (1 + 2 n)
```

Assuming the derivative is with respect to n:

```
g[1, 2, n]

(*1/3 n (1 + n) + 1/6 n (1 + 2 n) + 1/6 (1 + n) (1 + 2 n)*)

g[2, 2, n]

(*(2 n)/3 + 1/3 (1 + 2 n + 2 (1 + n))*)

g[3, 2, n]

(*2*)
```

To evaluate at zero and divide by `j!`:

```
g[j, 2, n]/j! /. j -> 2 /. n -> 0
```

Comment: Ah, thank you!  I think you mean $g[j_, a_, n_\,] := D[f[n, a], \{n, j\}]$, but it works perfectly!

Comment: @james Oops. Yep. Right in code, wrong in Answer. Fixing now.

Answer (score 3):

The origin of the problem is a small bug appearing in your code here : `Derivative[1, 0][HarmonicNumber]` (even though this expression evaluates correctly in general, however  you should have rather `Derivative[1, 0][#1 &][r, 0]`! ) for `[r,0]`.

Since we've had :

```
f[n_, a_] = Sum[i^(a), {i, 1, n}]
```

> ```
> HarmonicNumber[n, -a]
> ```

This result is a polynomial in `n` for any natural number `a`, e.g. :

```
And @@ (PolynomialQ[#, n] & /@ Sum[i^(Range[100]), {i, 1, n}])
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Then if you evaluate `g[d, a, n]` setting numeric values `d` and `a` such that `d == a + 1`, subsequently your system will encounter the message evaluating :

```
Derivative[1, 0][HarmonicNumber][r, 0]
```

> ```
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered. >>
>
> Indeterminate
> ```

You can find out this issue checking the output of e.g. :

```
g[3, 2, r] // Trace
```

`Zeta[1]` alone (which yields `ComplexInfinity`) doesn't produce the message, however this derivative :

```
Derivative[1, 0][HarmonicNumber]
```

> ```
> #2 (Zeta[#2 + 1] - HarmonicNumber[#1, #2 + 1]) &
> ```

does when evaluated on `[r,0]` i.e. it yields `0  Zeta[1]` which is `Indeterminate`.

One can get rid of the problem simply defining e.g.

```
f[n_, a_] = Sum[ i^(a), {i, 1, n}]; 
g1[d_, a_, n_] := D[ f[n, a], {n, d}]
```

i.e. substituting `Set` (`=`)  in `g` by `SetDelayed` (`:=`) and `Derivative` operator by `D`. See e.g. [Assignments](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Assignments.html) ( `lhs = rhs` — immediate assignment, with rhs evaluated at the time of assignment, and  `lhs := rhs` — delayed assignment, with rhs reevaluated every time it is used ). Moreover `Derivative` is a functional operator acting on functions unlike `D` which acts on expressions.  This post on Wolfram Blog you may find useful : [Three Functions for Computing Derivatives](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/05/20/mathematica-qa-three-functions-for-computing-derivatives/).

Applying the above definition of `g1` we get :

```
{ g1[5, 5, n], g1[3, 2, n], g1[4, 3, n], g1[3, 10, n], g1[21, 20, n]}
```

> ```
> { 60 + 120 n, 2, 6, -3 + 60 n^2 - 210 n^4 + 420 n^6 + 360 n^7 + 90 n^8, 2432902008176640000}
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did just that!

Comment: @james I extended my answer to explain the issue more extensively.